# How do i get my account to show up on someone elses device?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

My friend has been trying to view my YouTube channel on her phone but it won't show up. How do I get it to show up? Is it like a privacy feature that i need to turn off?

Comment: There's no privacy feature to turn on/off. Are you sure you have a Youtube channel and not just a Google account? (having a Google account doesn't automatically create a Youtube channel for you, you have to create it manually). If you go to your channel yourself, copy its URL and send it to your friend, what happens? Can she see it?